# Formatting datetimes without two digits in month and day?

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, timestamp

I have a dataframe that has a particular column with datetimes in a format outputted in the following format:

```
df['A']
1/23/2008 15:41
3/10/2010 14:42
10/14/2010 15:23
1/2/2008 11:39
4/3/2008 13:35
5/2/2008 9:29
```

I need to convert `df['A']` into `df['Date']`, `df['Time']`, and `df['Timestamp']`.

I tried to first convert `df['A']` to a datetime by using

```
df['Datetime'] = pd.to_datetime(df['A'],format='%m/%d/%y %H:%M')
```

from which I would've created my three columns above, but my formatting codes for `%m/%d` do not pick up the single digit month and days.

Does anyone know a quick fix to this?

Comment: Pandas is smart: `pd.to_datetime(df['A'])`

Comment: Your format is incorrect, if you ignore the format, pandas parses it properly by default.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a bug with your format. As @MaxU [commented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48216417/formatting-datetimes-without-two-digits-in-month-and-day/48216465#comment83414781_48216417), if you don't pass a `format` argument, then pandas will automagically convert your column to `datetime`.

```
df['Timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(df['A'])
```

Or, to fix your code -

```
df['Timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(df['A'], format='%m/%d/%Y %H:%M')
```

---

For your first query, use `dt.normalize` or, `dt.floor` (thanks, MaxU, for the suggestion!) -

```
df['Date'] = df['Timestamp'].dt.normalize()
```

Or,

```
df['Date'] = df['Timestamp'].dt.floor('D')
```

For your second query, use `dt.time`.

```
df['Time'] = df['Timestamp'].dt.time
```

```
df.drop('A', 1)

        Date      Time           Timestamp
0 2008-01-23  15:41:00 2008-01-23 15:41:00
1 2010-03-10  14:42:00 2010-03-10 14:42:00
2 2010-10-14  15:23:00 2010-10-14 15:23:00
3 2008-01-02  11:39:00 2008-01-02 11:39:00
4 2008-04-03  13:35:00 2008-04-03 13:35:00
5 2008-05-02  09:29:00 2008-05-02 09:29:00
```

Comment: we could also use `df['Timestamp'].dt.floor('D')` instead of `df['Timestamp'].dt.normalize()`...

Comment: Always super helpful. Thank you @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ and @MaxU!

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can use `%-m` instead of `%m`, if this works in the same way as `strftime()` function.

Comment: nope, it gives: `ValueError: '-' is a bad directive in format '%-m/%d/%y %H:%M'` :(